# How to store odd numbers in C from one array to another sequentially (in order) and returning the total number added?

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile a code that takes a size parameter of an array, takes all the odd numbers and stores them in order sequentially, then showing the number of...numbers...added. But it's not working and I don't know why.

```
int CopySelected(const int array[], int size, int odd_numbers[])
{
    
    int i=0;
    
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if (array[i]%2!=0) {
          odd_numbers[i] = array[i];
        }
    }
    
    return (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
}
```

I know the sizeof(array) needs to be referred with a pointer and that I should use std:: instead, but I can't in this particular case. Referencing them in a *x and declaring &x at the end didn't work as well. And ignoring that bit, I don't know why isn't it appending the numbers to the new array.

I also tried this, but this didn't work either. Sorry for the noob questions

```
for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if (array[i]%2!=0) {
          odd_numbers[i] += 1;
          
        }
    }
```

Comment: Suppose `array` starts with `{ 2, 5, 6, ... }` ... you want to skip `array[0]` and *use* `array[1]` which looks ok ... **BUT** you're also using the same index for the `odd_numbers` array which is wrong: you want `odd_numbers[0] = array[1];`

Comment: ...oh, and `return (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));` will not work. `array` is not an array. It's a `const int*` and has no concept of how many elements there are. If it would know that, you wouldn't have to pass in a `size` parameter to the function.

Comment: The mention of `std::` makes me wonder if you're writing C code in C++ and using a C++ compiler. If so, _don't do this._

Comment: @Omer Rudnick, If the [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77398526/2410359) does not work for you, you need to post the calling code too, a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

There is a couple of serious problems with this short fragment of code.

### One

```
odd_numbers[i] = array[i];
```

This copies odd numbers from one array to *the same positions* in the other array. Other positions (those that are occupied by even numbers) are left untouched. So if the original array contained

```
(0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 2)
```

the resulting array will contain

```
(?, 1, ?, ?, ?, 3, ?)
```

where `?` is any old garbage.

### Fix

You want to initialise elements of `odd_numbers` sequentially: the one at position 0, then the one at position 1, then the one at position 2, etc. For that you need a separate counter.

```
int counter = 0;
for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
    if (array[i]%2!=0) {
      odd_numbers[counter++] = array[i];
    }
}
```

### Two & Three

```
return (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
```

There are at least two problems at once here.

First, `sizeof(array)` doesn't do what you probably expect. `array` is a *pointer*, despite being declared with `[]`. `sizeof(array)` is the size of the pointer (typically 4 or 8 bytes), not the size of the array it points to.

Second, even if `sizeof(array)` would magically return the size of the array (it doesn't), it would not help you because the array is not fully occupied. You need the number of odd numbers you put there, not the total number of elements.

### Fix

Fortunately there is an easy fix.

```
return counter;
```

This is exactly the number of odd elements you copied from the input array.